# How to integrate the offline mode in my flutter application? I'm using MySQL server

Tags: flutter, thread-synchronization

How to sync data between MySQL server and Sqflite in flutter? I just want to integrate the offline mode in my flutter app...
Is there any library for this?

Comment: Add an update timestamp to MqSql tables. When your app end, record a timestamp. When it starts again merge any data from MySql with a timestamp greater than your local closing timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no library for this. But, it should be pretty straight forward to implement. Just follow these 3 points:

1) Create a `function` for initial upload of data on `SQFLite` on from `MySQL` database when for eg: when a user enables offline mode, or logins for the first time, etc. whatever is relevant to your use case.

2) Then you have to have another `function` which when the user is online, checks if `SQFLite` data is in sync with `MySQL`, if not it updates `SQFLite` database (This step is unnecessary if the `MySql` database for the user can only be modified by the user, in which case just the 3rd point is sufficient)

3) Another `function` is required where when the user changes `MySQL` data(read, updated, deletes), `SQFLite` data is updated by recent `MySQL` data.

If you know basic querying of `MySQL` and `SQFlite` (which is quite similar) and are familiar with deserializing data, this should be easy to implement.